# How to exclude multiple values of column using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, orm

I want to filter **mytable** & get rows where name does not contain `''` or `'-'` values and for this purpose I have used below query but does not working.

`mytable.objects.exclude(name = ['','-']).order_by('name').count()` returning 2000 all rows and whereas query `mytable.objects.exclude(name = '').order_by('name').count()` working perfectly and returning filtered 1460 results.

Below one is my **Postgresql** query which is working perfectly fine and returning **1450** results excluding name values of `['','-']`.

`select * from mytable where name != '-' and name != ''  order by -id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
mytable.objects.exclude(name__in=['', '-'])
```

This should exclude the rows matching the values you've passed in the list.

And you don't need to do `order_by()` for getting the count.

Just use the `.count()` directly on queryset.

Comment: thanks buddy , able to achieve my task & by the way I have used `order_by()` to sort values by name & count is just for testing purpose.